# how to know all requests done in nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

i want to make custom loading page,

after all requests or static data like (static image - some library) loaded, i want to hide loading page.

so how i can check if requests & static data loaded or done?

i'm tring with this code but not work for me

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loading" class="fixed left-0 top-0 w-full z-50 bg-green-500 h-screen" />
  <NuxtPage v-else />
</template>

<script setup>
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp();
const loading = ref(false);
nuxtApp.hook("page:start", () => {
  loading.value = true;
});
nuxtApp.hook("page:finish", () => {
  loading.value = false;
});
</script>
```

Comment: Parent can't know when async operations finish inside child component.  Whatever NuxtPages you have will need to watch those operations themselves and emit to the parent to signal when all loading is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

Note: This will only work for the static file requests.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    {{ loading }}
    <NuxtPage />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const nuxtApp = useNuxtApp()
const loading = ref(true)
nuxtApp.hook("page:finish", () => {
  loading.value = false
})
</script>
```